# Grouping Duplicates under Common values JavaScript(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know is there is a way I can group Common values between two groups. Ie removes the duplicates from the two and put it under Common Columns and leave the distinct in a separate group.

Currently

[image: Currently]
[image: To this]

To This

Sorry, I am still a beginner in JQuery.

Comment: The one on the right is what I am after. Thanks.

Comment: if you have a relationship to child elements and parent element, yes you can to that. Did you try any code? you can use tree view plugin too